# How to plot grid of histograms by categorical variable in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, visualization

I have a dataset containing 50 numeric variables and 1 categorical variable (segment_hc_print, having 6 categories). I want to see the spread of each variable in each category by plotting a grid of histogram, where each row would represent a category, column would represent the variable and each cell in a grid is a histogram. I am trying the code below to generate grid for single variable :

```
def grid_histogram(variable, bins):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
    fig.set_size_inches(10,10, forward = True)
    fig.suptitle(variable, fontsize = 8)
    plt.locator_params(numticks = 4)

    for i in np.arange(0, 6, 1):
        ax = plt.subplot(6,1,i+1)
        ax.hist(sensor_df_print_sample_v2[sensor_df_print_sample_v2.segment_hc_print == i][variable], bins)
        ax.set_title("cluster = " + str(i), fontsize = 5)
        ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
        ax.set_yticks(np.round(np.linspace(ymin, ymax, 3), 2))
        xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
        ax.set_xticks(np.round(np.linspace(xmin, xmax,3),2))
        plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation = 'vertical', fontsize = 4)

    fig.tight_layout()
    fig.savefig(str(variable) + '_histogram.pdf')
    plt.show()
```

And this is what I am getting :
[sample histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADOKv.png)

How do I generate a grid of such histograms, each variable stacked to the right of another ?
This code below generates the ideal size of histogram I need.
[sample histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHNuU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly, you could just create a grid with `plt.subplots()`. In the example below, I am plotting the first 5 variables as columns:

```
nr_of_categories = 6
nr_of_variables = 5

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = nr_of_categories, cols = nr_of_variables, figsize = (20, 20))

for category in np.arange(0, nr_of_categories):
  for variable in np.arange(0, nr_of_variables):
    ax[category, variable].hist(sensor_df_print_sample_v2[sensor_df_print_sample_v2.segment_hc_print == i][variable], bins)

    # and then the rest of your code where you replace ax with ax[category, variable]
```